# Casting an string to float javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, char

I have an string defining the lattitude of an event with this format "p002.155" and "n003.196" being "p" and "n" the form the system define if the number is positive or negative.

I need to parse the string to float, tried with parseFloat but keeps getting NaN value because of the char inside the string

how can I do it?? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the char and then convert to float:

```js
var str = "n002.155";
str = +str.replace("p","").replace("n","-"); //here the leading `+` is casting to number
console.log(str);
```

Comment: @ALEXANDERRAMIREZ if you don't mind, if it's working for you, check this answer as accepted please

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring and look at the first char

```js
function getFloat(str) {
  var sign = str.charAt(0)=="n"?-1:1;
  return parseFloat(str.substring(1))*sign;
}

var latPStr = "p002.155", latNStr = "n003.196";
console.log(getFloat(latPStr),getFloat(latNStr));
```

Comment: I often get downvotes when I post working solutions in js - not sure why but js users really don't like working answers, unless it was the first to be upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string to float like this:

```
var str = '3.8';
var fl= +(str);  //fl is a variable converted to float
console.log( +(str) );
console.log("TYPE OF FL IS THIS "+typeof fl);
```

+(string) will cast string into float.

Comment: Reading the question is always useful. How does this convert a string like "n003.196" to a float?

Comment: Why is this voted up at all? there is no handling of n/p